# Cordova Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'

Tags: firebase, cordova, build, admob

I am getting this error in Cordova, i use the cordova-plugin-firebasex without any problem, when i add the plugin cordova-plugin-admob-free it gives this error and fails to build. I have been trying to solve it for days, i'm using cordova version 9, any help would be great !

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users**.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-gass-11.0.4.aar\7c8749a76f488f62bc9294a2b72be741\jars\classes.jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and fixed it by editing `platforms/android/project.properties`

Change

`cordova.system.library.16=com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.4
cordova.system.library.17=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4`

To

`cordova.system.library.16=com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+
cordova.system.library.17=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+`